# Connecting to Outlook Web (OWA) via a desktop client

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, windows-live-mail

I'm having all kinds of timeout problem with the web-based client for Outlook Online (microsoftonline.com), and I'd like to use something like Live Mail to connect instead.

So, can I use Live Mail to do that?  If so, how do I configure it?

If I can't use Live Mail, are there any desktop clients that can connect (I'd like to retain access to the calendar, etc)?

UPDATE: I installed a "Sign In" program I just found at microsoftonline.com, and now I can switch between two Exchange servers (I'm a consultant, so there's the client's server and my company's server) with Outlook, but I can't have both open at the same time (which would be preferable).

Comment: Using strictly Microsoft software, you can never be synced with Exchange twice in the same profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I can't have both open at the same time (which would be preferable).

You may want to look at [ExtraOutlook](http://lifehacker.com/5060667/extraoutlook-runs-two-instances-of-outlook).

Comment: EXCELLENT!  This is EXACTLY what I need.  You are awesome.